# is there a way to scrape the underlying data of a particular button?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

1. I'm trying to scrape a webpage, for few elements using class attribute I got the data but the problem is when my loop is going to each URL to extract the information then it should extract the contact number.

Contact number is not directly available, when we click "CALL NOW" button then a pop up card is opening to show the contact number.

I tried using the class function of that phone number element but still, I'm not getting the phone number.

```
try:
    contact = soup.find('div', class_= 'c-vn-full__number u-bold').text.strip()
except:
    contact = "N/A"
```

Is there any way to achieve the result?

2. Also I left with one more element to extract "consulting fees"(Price) as a text but it has no class attribute

[image]

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: @baduker, Could you please provide me your email id, I can share my code and send url link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.practo.com/Bangalore/doctor/dr-venkata-krishna-rao-diabetologist-1?practice_id=776084&specialization=general%20physician"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser").select(".u-no-margin--top")[-1]
print(soup.getText())
```

Output:

```
₹400
```

EDIT:

To get contact details, you need to get `practice_id`, `doctor_id`, and `query_string` from the source `HTML`. There's a huge `JSON` embedded there but I thought it's less hassle just scooping out the necessary parts rather than parsing this monster.

Once you have all the parts, you can use an endpoint to get the contact details.

Here's how to get this done:

```python
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.practo.com/Bangalore/doctor/" \
      "dr-venkata-krishna-rao-diabetologist-1?" \
      "practice_id=776084&specialization=general%20physician"
page = requests.get(url).text

query_string_pattern = re.compile(r"query_string\":\"(.*?)\"")
practice_doctor_uuid = re.compile(
    r"(practice|doctor)_id\":"
    r"\"([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12})"
)

practice_id, doctor_id = [i[1] for i in re.findall(practice_doctor_uuid, page)[:2]]
query_string = re.search(query_string_pattern, page).group(1)

practice_url = "https://www.practo.com/health/api/vn/vnpractice"
query = f"{query_string}&practice_uuid={practice_id}&doctor_uuid={doctor_id}"
endpoint_url = f"{practice_url}{query}"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
}

contact_info = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers).json()
print(json.dumps(contact_info["vn_phone_number"], indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "number": "+918046801985",
  "operator": "VOICE",
  "vn_zone_id": 1,
  "country_code": "IN",
  "extension": true,
  "id": 49090
}
```

Comment: How? 
My url links are in loop stored in list called doctorslinks = [], now how can i incorporate the above code which can take urls from loop and find out the consulting fees. @baduker

Comment: Loop over the soups you make from those urls? And don't forget to up-vote / accept if you find the answer useful.

Comment: I'm trying my best to put the above code in the loop to test and also i would like to know is there any way to achieve the result for the problem I requested in the point one above to get the contact no.?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add the code there.